# How to create multiple sqlplus tables using one SQL script file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am creating a whole bunch of tables in SQL*Plus and using PsPad to write SQL script that running the script through sqlplus in putty.

Currently I have to create an individual SQL script file for each table but I would like to create all of my tables in one SQL script file. Is this possible?

I have tried

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE4(
ID NUMBER(2),NAME VARCHAR2 (50));
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE2(
ID_NO NUMBER (2), SIZE NUMBER (4));
```

And also leaving a line between the tables

Comment: What you posted should work. Do you get an error? Is that the complete script? You need provide far more detail than that.

Comment: It makes the first table but not the second. I get the error "ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIZE is a keyword if you want to create a column named SIZE you should put it between "".

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE2(ID_NO NUMBER (2), "SIZE" NUMBER (4));
```

As you can see in the comments i should have said that you can do this but it doesn't mean that you should.Thanks for for clarification fellas.

Comment: Yes, but don't do that anyway, since you'll have to always quote it wherever it's referenced in the future. There's a [list of reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_keywd001.htm); note the first paragraph, and avoid using any of them for object names if you can.

Comment: SIZE is the problem but *please* don't use quoted identifiers for your column / table names. A lot of tools don't fully support quoted identifiers. Call the column <entity name>size or something. create table test (" " varchar2(10),"ORA-00942 Table or view does not exist" integer);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [anonymous PL/SQL blocks](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch15_03.htm) which can contain multiple statements.

Comment: But not DDL unless you use dynamic SQL.